# SMTP error using Gmail to send email on PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Error:

```
SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? (18313040)
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. no photos' requests in pending!
```

I get this error when using Gmail domain to send mail through my PHP script.

Comment: Your install of PHP doesn't support SSL encryption, which you need.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post the code relevant to the question. You can do so by editing your own question, and adding it there, in the body of the question. It will help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your PHP configuration and see that php_openssl.dll is installed/enabled.

Comment: need to open the php.ini and find the line ";extension=php_openssl.dll"; just remove the ';'.

Comment: thankx! @greg P solved the problem. waiting for the email to be received!

Comment: Glad I could help - hope you "Accept" the answer then :)